# Shotwell 0.32.2 (snap) not importing HEIC files in fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: shotwell, 23.10, heic

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 23.10 which is using kernel 6.5.0

I installed the Shotwell snap via App Center.

When importing HEIC files it fails. The log doesn't give any reason for the failure. Most other formats (jpeg, png etc) import just fine.
Here's the shotwell error log:

```
Import Results Report (Shotwell 0.32.2 @ 2023-12-12)

Attempted to import 8763 files. Of these, 4714 files were successfully imported.

Photos/Videos Not Imported for Other Reasons:

/home/montecristo/Pictures/2023/08/07/IMG_0038.HEIC
    error message: 

/home/montecristo/Pictures/2023/08/08/IMG_0085.HEIC
    error message: 

/home/montecristo/Pictures/2018/08/11/IMG_0098.HEIC
    error message:
```

The numbers tie up that all the HEIC files are the errors

I thought it might be a package issue.

After searching for solutions, I installed packages `heif-gdk-pixbuf` and `heif-thumbnailer`. No apparent effect (although I can now see HEIC thumbnails in nautilus).

Here's the output of `apt list | grep heif`:

```
heif-gdk-pixbuf/mantic,now 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
heif-thumbnailer/mantic,now 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
kodi-imagedecoder-heif/mantic 20.1.0+ds1-3 amd64
libheif-dev/mantic 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64
libheif-examples/mantic 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64
libheif-plugin-aomdec/mantic 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64
libheif-plugin-aomenc/mantic,now 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libheif-plugin-dav1d/mantic,now 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libheif-plugin-libde265/mantic,now 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libheif-plugin-rav1e/mantic 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64
libheif-plugin-svtenc/mantic 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64
libheif-plugin-x265/mantic,now 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libheif1/mantic,now 1.16.2-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
librust-libheif-rs-dev/mantic 0.20.0-2 amd64
librust-libheif-sys-dev/mantic 1.16.2-1 amd64
```

and

`apt list | grep gstreamer`

```
baresip-gstreamer/mantic 1.0.0-4build8 amd64
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/mantic,now 1.22.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer-qapt/mantic 3.0.5-2 amd64
gstreamer1.0-adapter-pulseeffects/mantic 4.8.7-2 amd64
gstreamer1.0-alsa/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-autogain-pulseeffects/mantic 4.8.7-2 amd64
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/mantic 3.0.27-3 amd64
gstreamer1.0-convolver-pulseeffects/mantic 4.8.7-2 amd64
gstreamer1.0-crystalizer-pulseeffects/mantic 4.8.7-2 amd64
gstreamer1.0-espeak/mantic 0.5.0-1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-fdkaac/mantic 1.20.0-1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-gl/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-gtk3/mantic 1.22.6-1ubuntu1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-libav/mantic,now 1.22.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-libcamera/mantic 0.1.0-3ubuntu1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-nice/mantic 0.1.21-2 amd64
gstreamer1.0-omx-bellagio-config/mantic 1.22.4-1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-omx-generic-config/mantic 1.22.4-1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-omx-generic/mantic 1.22.4-1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-opencv/mantic-updates,mantic-security 1.22.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-packagekit/mantic,now 1.2.7-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-pipewire/mantic,now 0.3.79-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-apps/mantic-updates,mantic-security 1.22.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/mantic-updates,mantic-security 1.22.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/mantic,now 1.22.6-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-rtp/mantic 1.14.4.1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/mantic,now 1.22.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-pocketsphinx/mantic 0.8.0+real5prealpha+1-15ubuntu1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/mantic 1.22.6-1ubuntu1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-python3-plugin-loader/mantic 1.22.5-1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-qt5/mantic 1.22.6-1ubuntu1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-qt6/mantic 1.22.6-1ubuntu1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-rtsp/mantic 1.22.6-1 amd64
gstreamer1.0-tools/mantic,now 1.22.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-vaapi/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-x/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcanberra-gstreamer/mantic 0.30-10ubuntu4 amd64
libextractor-plugin-gstreamer/mantic 1:1.11-8 amd64
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-ocaml-dev/mantic 0.3.1-4 amd64
libgstreamer-ocaml/mantic 0.3.1-4 amd64
libgstreamer-opencv1.0-0/mantic-updates,mantic-security 1.22.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/mantic-updates,mantic-security,now 1.22.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev/mantic-updates,mantic-security 1.22.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/mantic,now 1.22.6-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev/mantic 1.22.6-1 amd64
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/mantic,now 1.22.6-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev/mantic 1.22.6-1ubuntu1 amd64
libgstreamer1.0-0/mantic,now 1.22.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer1.0-dev/mantic 1.22.5-1 amd64
libgstreamerd-3-0/mantic 3.10.0-2 amd64
libgstreamerd-3-dev/mantic 3.10.0-2 amd64
libgstreamermm-1.0-1/mantic 1.10.0+dfsg-4 amd64
libgstreamermm-1.0-dev/mantic 1.10.0+dfsg-4 amd64
libgstreamermm-1.0-doc/mantic 1.10.0+dfsg-4 all
libgtk-4-media-gstreamer/mantic-updates,now 4.12.3+ds-1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 amd64
libqt5gstreamer-dev/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 amd64
libqt5gstreamerquick-1.0-0/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 amd64
libqt5gstreamerui-1.0-0/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 amd64
libqt5gstreamerutils-1.0-0/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 amd64
librust-gstreamer-audio-dev/mantic 0.21.0-3 amd64
librust-gstreamer-audio-sys-dev/mantic 0.21.0-4 amd64
librust-gstreamer-base-dev/mantic 0.21.0-3 amd64
librust-gstreamer-base-sys-dev/mantic 0.21.0-3 amd64
librust-gstreamer-dev/mantic 0.21.0-3 amd64
librust-gstreamer-player-dev/mantic 0.21.0-0ubuntu2 amd64
librust-gstreamer-player-sys-dev/mantic 0.21.0-2 amd64
librust-gstreamer-sys-dev/mantic 0.21.0-4 amd64
librust-gstreamer-video-dev/mantic 0.21.0-3 amd64
librust-gstreamer-video-sys-dev/mantic 0.21.0-4 amd64
mkchromecast-gstreamer/mantic 0.3.9~git20200902+db2964a-2.1 all
phonon-backend-gstreamer-common/mantic 4:4.10.0-1build1 amd64
phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer/mantic 4:4.10.0-1build1 amd64
qml-module-qtgstreamer/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 amd64
qtgstreamer-doc/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 all
qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5/mantic 1.2.0-5.2 amd64
ruby-gstreamer/mantic 3.4.3-1+ubuntu7 amd64
```

Could it be that `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` package is missing? That tries to install 74MB of a large number of packages.

I understood that snaps should come with all packages needed exactly to avoid this sort of issue.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve or what to try?

Comment: Installing packages via APT will not resolve the problem - snap packages are run in a confined environment with no access to the system's packages. Or, to say it the other way round: the system's packages are not visible / accessible of the snap.

Comment: You should report a bug here: https://github.com/ubuntu/shotwell/issues

Comment: Yes it appears to be a bug in the shotwell 0.32.2 snap. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the snap. Same issue. I removed it again and installed the deb repository version and all now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Shotwell from Ubuntu deb repository instead of the snap package

```
$ sudo snap remove --purge shotwell
$ sudo apt install heif-gdk-pixbuf shotwell
```

Comment: Probably it should be added here for people reading this thread that Shotwell adss HEIC support starting with release 0.32, which is available from the Ubuntu repos for 23.10 Mantic and newer. Older Ubuntu release of 23.04 and before have older Shotwell release in their repos which do not have HEIC support yet.